# azure linux vm recovery - unable to remote login

Tags: azure

forgot user name password for a linux (ubuntu) vm. tried to "Reset Remote Access" from the portal, but it is not helping - more than 30 minutes - it still shown in progress. Tried to do it via azure command line. Created a new user with password, but unable to login. SSH says access denied. Should I do any additional steps?

Answer (score 0):

After creating new user you should also reset your SSH connection. You could refer to [Reset Access and Manage Users and Check Disks with the Azure VMAccess Extension for Linux](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-use-vmaccess-reset-password-or-ssh/) for detailed steps.